# Error when assigning to a data.frame column indexed with a factor

Tags: r, subset, variable-assignment

Let me preface this question by saying that I realise it's generally not ideal to use a factor as an index, given that the factor will be coerced to numeric and may not represent what you want it to.

Given that, however, I was curious to encounter the following error when trying to assign to a data.frame that has been subset with a factor.

Take the following reproducible example:

`alpha <- data.frame('a' = c(1, 2), 'b' = c(4, 3))
index <- factor(c(2, 1))
alpha[index[1], ]`

So far so good. It seems that the index vector is being coerced to numeric and suitably subsetting the alpha data.frame.

However, trying to assign to the subsetted row gives a variety of errors

`alpha[index[1], ] <- c(1, 2)`

> "Error in Summary.factor(2L, na.rm = FALSE): ‘max’ not meaningful for factors"

I have also seen the same error message with min instead of max in a different case. Here I also get

> "In Ops.factor(i, 0L) : ‘>=’ not meaningful for factors"

Since `<-` is a primitive it's hard to inspect what's going on under the surface here. Does anyone have insight into why this breaks down?

Comment: It may be worth inspecting the source for ```[<-.data.frame```; it looks like there is a `max(i)` in there.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for the link to the correct source. Looks like there's a few min/max checks to make sure the subscripts aren't out of bounds. And since it doesn't check for factor and convert to numeric, they fail. Not sure if that would be considered a bug or intentional.

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question, but you can workaround by `alpha[as.numeric(index[1]), ] <- c(1,2)`